# Получить match определенной группы захвата

Tags: perl, active-perl

Есть код:

```
my $Condition = "(?|Процедура|Функция)[\\s]+(?:.+?)[(][^)]*[)][\\s]+(?:Экспорт)*(?<body>.*?)(?|конецпроцедуры|конецфункции)";


my @MethodBody = $+{body} =~ /$Condition/msgiu;
```

в MethodBody всего один элемент, а должно быть много.
Эта же регулярка на regex101.com

[image: Пример]
К примеру, если я сделаю так:

```
my @MethodBody = $txt =~ /$Condition/msgiu;
```

то все работает как мне нужно, однако тогда в массив попадают все группы захвата, можно конечно применять ?:, но блин должен быть иной способ.

Comment: скиньте пожалуйста ссылку с вашей регуляркой и данными на regex101.com

Comment: не знал, что на regex101 можно сохранять ))
https://regex101.com/r/uxH6Ez/1

После перехода по ссылке регулярка почему-то не работает, а внесешь правку в патерн и норм, достаточно добавить и удалить пробел

Comment: Боюсь другого способа нет, собственно `?:` для того и придуман, что бы не делать захвата. любой лишний захват помимо неудобств при выдаче еще и кучу лишней памяти съедает и тормозит

Comment: И думаю можно сократить регулярку скажем до `^(?|Процедура|Функция).*?$(.*?)^(?|конецпроцедуры|конецфункции)` работает на порядок быстрее (даже regexp101 таймаут не выдает), точность вроде не страдает (если процедры/функции начинаются в начале новой строки). И содержит всего одну группу захвата. Можно `\s*` добавить, если опасаетесь что слово Процедура/Функция может быть с отступом

Comment: Или можно использовать последовательное чтение из регулярки вида `while(регулярка)` вместо формирования массива, тогда внутри на каждой итерации вам доступны все группы захвата